# Why isn't my third condition working in search?

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to get a searched result and I have the following code:

```
public function search(Request $request){ 
    $from = $request->from;
    $to = $request->to;
    $word = $request->word;  
    if(empty($word) || $word == null){
        $searched = Post::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->paginate(10);
    } elseif(!empty($word) && !empty($from) && !empty($to)){ 
        $searched = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $word . '%')
        ->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%' . $word . '%')
        ->orWhere('subtitle', 'LIKE', '%' . $word . '%')
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])
        ->paginate(10); 
    } elseif(empty($from) && empty($to) && !empty($word)){
        $searched = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $word . '%')
        ->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%' . $word . '%')
        ->orWhere('subtitle', 'LIKE', '%' . $word . '%')
        ->paginate(10);
    }

    return view('page.search', compact('searched', 'from', 'to'));
}
```

The first and second condition are working but not the last. What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to check the last condition, must be something opposite of expected that is why it is not working.

Comment: In your 3rd `elseif` you checked that if `$from` & `$to` is empty and `$word` is not empty, but from your first `if` condition, it's fullfill the condition while execute that `$word` is empty, that's why it's return from there!! If you want to debug just put `echo` statement to debug.

Comment: @HirenGohel To fulfill the first condition $word should be empty but it is not.

Comment: Have you putted the `echo` statement in every if and elseif? Check first that in which condition its going and make it as you want!

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "not working"? What have you tried to debug that problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase There is name tag in my form but when I only field the word I am not getting anything while debugging $request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

- for example if word found then search with like  then first condition
  true
- if user set from and to date then second condition true
- if user fill both(word and date) then your both condition true..
- if your does not fill any value then get first 10(ten) posts only(none of condition match)

  ```
  public function search(Request $request){

      $posts = Post::query();
      $from = $request->from;
      $to = $request->to;
      $word = trim($request->word);

      if($word && !empty($word)){
             $posts->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $word . '%')
              ->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%' . $word . '%')
              ->orWhere('subtitle', 'LIKE', '%' . $word . '%');
      }

      if(!empty($from) && !empty($to)){
          $posts->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to]);
      }

      $searched = $posts->paginate(10);

      return view('page.search', compact('searched', 'from', 'to'));
  }
  ```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what do you mean by "automatically matched"?

Comment: What if the user enters value in all field you have only showed to cases.

Comment: @NicoHaase i forget to add explation now add so pl check

Comment: @JigneshJoisar Thank you for helping. But I want to display message if the form is submitted empty. How can do that?